# Would ec2_sd work with blackbox in prometheus?

Tags: go, prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Would ec2_sd work with blackbox in prometheus? I want to automatically ping the machines. The exporter supports only static configs.

Comment: Hello, could please explain better what you want to do and what you have tried ?

Comment: I want blackbox exporter to ping my machines in aws. I want it to automatically discover the ec2 ip's or aws domain names and ping them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service discovery is independent of blackbox exporter configuration, so this will work the same way static_configs do. See https://www.robustperception.io/testing-ssh-of-hosts-from-consul for example.